# IBM WAS HTTPS connection certificate chain error

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, websphere

I have IBM WAS 8.5.5.9 ND and MS Exchange server which I try to access with EWS Java API. Deployment manager is set on one machine, my app server with java app runs on other machine.

```
         ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
         ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "host");
         service.setCredentials(credentials);
         service.setUrl(URI.create("https://xxxxxxxxx/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));

         List msgList = new ArrayList();

         Folder folder = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
         FindItemsResults results = service.findItems(folder.getId(), new ItemView(5));
         List items = results.getItems();

         service.close();
```

But my app fails to acceess MS Exchange. HTTPS connection problems:

```
The request failed. The request failed. com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
            java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=XXX Root CA, O=XXX, C=ES is not trusted; internal cause is: 
            java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
```

I have founded this IBM guide (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592616).

I downloaded root and intermediate certificates from my firefox browser with which I can acceess OWA. Installed them in NodeDefaultTrustStore and even in CellDefaultTrustStore, reloaded my app server with java EWS API running on it. But still have this problem.

What did I do wrong? Maybe I missed something? Is this problem connected to IBW WAS and truststore settings or I just have wrong certificates? Shoul I add this certificates to java truststore ? Is value of Alias field in adding singer certificates important (I made alias value for my intermediate certificate other than *trusted*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I also had to add root and intermediate certificates in java truststore